# iOS youtube player loads in main thread

Tags: ios, swift, webview, youtube-api, gpuimage

Context: I use GPUImage2 to filter and render the camera preview and to record it. During the preview, I use Youtube player api to load and show a video.

Youtube player is a webview, it freezes a bit the camera preview on loading, which is annoying but acceptable.
The main issue is that while the player is shown, pausing or playing, my camera preview is laggy. The preview reacts slowly when I move the phone, some timers I use may be irregular. In cases where there is no player, the preview is fluid.

Is the youtube player so heavy on main thread?
Is it so heavy work to process camera frames and  playing video in WebView at the same time?

Comment: You may want to try displaying big things on a small screen with Scroll View and keeping the main (UI) thread clear and unblocked with Multithreading as discussed in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oNl7qpUvQ1k&feature=youtu.be&t=3564) or see the [Complete Guide to YouTube Optimization: Everything You Need To Improve Your Channel](https://blog.bufferapp.com/youtube-optimization). See if it helps.

Comment: GPUImage operates on a background thread, largely independent of the main thread. It sounds like this is just a case of the system being overloaded. Try running your application through Instruments and see where it highlights bottlenecks and resource usage.

Comment: Hey Brad! Yeah, I am pretty sure that that's the YT webview is the main "slower" here. Without it, GPUImage is running great without freezing or lagging. My question is more about webview loading optimisation ;)